# Page not found error in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

```
  Protected Sub ImageButton3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton3.Click
        If ImageButton3.ImageUrl = ("./images/back.png") Then
            Me.Response.Redirect("http://www.volvobusesindia.com")
        Else
            Try
                Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
                Dim mail As New MailMessage()
                SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("info@volvobusesindia.com", "xxxxxx")
                SmtpServer.Port = 25
                SmtpServer.Host = "mail.volvobusesindia.com"
                mail = New MailMessage()
                mail.From = New MailAddress("info@volvobusesindia.com")
                mail.To.Add(Literal23.Text)
                mail.Subject = "VolvoBusesIndia:E-Ticket Confirmation"
                mail.Body = "<B>" + "||| -- VOLVOBUSESINDIA : E-Ticket Confirmation  -- |||" + "</B>" + "<BR><BR><BR>" + "<B>" + "PNR Number : " + "</B>" & " " & Literal2.Text + "<BR><BR>" + "<B>" + "Payment Reference Number : " + "</B>" & " " & Literal1.Text + "<BR><BR>" + "<B>" + "Ticket Number : " + "</B>" & " " & Literal3.Text + "<BR><BR>" + "<B>" + "Travels : " + "</B>" & " " & Literal4.Text + "<BR><BR>" + "<B>" + "From : " + "</B>" & " " & Literal7.Text + "<BR><BR>" + "<B>" + "To : " + "</B>" & " " & Literal8.Text + "<BR><BR>" + "<B>" + "Journey Date : " + "</B>" & " " & Literal10.Text + "<BR><BR>" + "<B>" + "Departure : " + "</B>" & " " & Literal11.Text + "<BR><BR>" + "<B>" + "Arrival : " + "</B>" & " " & Literal12.Text + "<BR><BR>" + "<B>" + "Boarding Point : " + "</B>" & " " & Literal13.Text + "<BR><BR>" + "<B>" + "Dropping Point : " + "</B>" & " " & Literal14.Text + "<BR><BR>" + "<B>" + "Seat Selected : " + "</B>" & " " & Literal15.Text + "<BR><BR>" + "<B>" + "Seat Opted : " + "</B>" & " " & Literal16.Text + "<BR><BR>" + "<B>" + "Bus Type : " + "</B>" & " " & Literal17.Text + "<BR><BR>" + "<B>" + "Total Amount : " + "</B>" & " " & Literal19.Text + "<BR><BR>" + "<B>" + "Payment Status : " + "</B>" & " " & Label1.Text + "<BR><BR>" + "<B>" + "Paid via : " + "</B>" & " " & Literal20.Text + "<BR><BR>" + "<B>" + "Message : " + "</B>" & " " + "<BR>" & "Volvo Buses India Wishes you a very Happy Journey, hope you satisfied with our services"
                mail.IsBodyHtml = True
                SmtpServer.Send(mail)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
            Try
                Using conn = New SqlConnection(constr)
                    Using cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
                        conn.Open()
                        Dim sql As String = "UPDATE a1_ticket SET BANK = @bank, PAID = @paid, BID = @bid WHERE Ticket_no = @ticketNo"
                        cmd.CommandText = sql
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bank", Literal20.Text)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paid", Label1.Text)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bid", Literal21.Text)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ticketNo", Literal3.Text)
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End Using
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                Response.Write(ex.Message)
            End Try
            Response.Redirect("~/eticket.aspx?Pno=" & Literal2.Text & "&tid=" & Literal22.Text & "&Status=" & "Print_ticket_success")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Page not found error occurs  ....but the pages are alredy uploaded ...

eticket.aspx and website http://www.volvobusesindia.com

Comment: Splashing a piece of code without more context is not a good way to ask a question. Please explain the purpose of the code, the expected result and the actual result.

Comment: @user594849 could you give us more info??, its a compiling problem?, data acces problem?, data visualization issue?, SQL syntax??

Comment: Sounds like he's getting a 404 when the page is used. Just debug it bit by bit - rem out the whole try blocks for the SMTP and DB update and see if it works. If it doesn't its probably one of the path references for the redirects. If it does work just let code back in. My money is on the redirect to "~/eticket.aspx" at the end though.

Comment: I'm closing my eyes to the switch condition based on what image is in the button at the time, and also the SMTP and DB update code placed directly in the event handler!

Comment: check your  web.config file. is there any error page set? if so check if that files exists.

Answer (score 1):

Check what controls the page is using, part of the error is:

> (or one of its dependencies)

This means that if for example you're using `MyControl.ascx` and such file doesn't exist, you'll get the same `404` error.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the page

```
 eticket.aspx
```

exists in the root folder of your application. A quick check online shows that eticket.aspx doesn't exist in the root of www.volvobusesindia.com.

Maybe your application is in a subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.volvobusesindia.com/eticket.aspx gives me 404 page not found exception. Can you check again for the existence of this page?

Comment: @user594849 - It is not available even on the new link that you provided to me.

Answer (score 0):

Few points:

1. Is your current context is clixngo.com or volvobusesindia. If its volvo buses india, then we are encounter 404.
2. Response.Redirect(~/..) will only work on current domain. for other domain you have to specify the whole string.